# What does "score points" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> It was roast beef for supper that evening and de Riviere had said, "A
> glass of red wine wouldn't go amiss," and scored some points for the
> laughter that followed."

I searched online dictionaries for [score points](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/score-points)
and there is two meanings:

- a) (also score off somebody) to say or do something in an attempt to
  prove that you are better or cleverer than someone else
- b) informal to do or say something to please someone or to make them
  respect you

I think (b) definition is fitted but I am not sure. And I don't understand the meaning of the sentence.

So, could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text:

> koni had gone into village and bought four bottles of wine in the
> Auberge du lac. It was roast beef for supper that evening and de
> Riviere had said, "A glass of red wine wouldn't go amiss," and
> **scored some points** for the laughter that followed. So after the meal Konrad went to the nursery, leant a ladder against the wall,
> climbed up it and tried in vain to pull the ladder up and let it down
> on the other side. For a moment he was about to aboundon his mission but the image of himself entering the room like a ruturning hero with his trophy of red wine was too sweet...

*Small World* by Martin Suter
Translated by Sandra Harper

- Note: The original german text is:  *Es hatte zum Abendessen
  Rindsbraten gegeben, und de Rivière hatte gesagt: »Ein Gläschen Roten
  dazu wäre nicht zu verachten«, und damit einen übertriebenen
  Lacherfolg verbucht.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a popular expression **to score brownie points**, meaning to do or say something that brings you approval or admiration, or that makes people laugh.

This expression is often shortened just to **to score points** (or **to lose points**).

It is said to arise from the points that junior girl guides (now referred to as scouts), who were formerly known as Brownies, earned for certain acknowledged skills.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/brownie--points
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/score-points

Comment: and what about the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: The expression indicates that his comment won the amused approval of those who listened to him. They liked what he said and found it funny.